# Why do I get ServletException - ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7

When I go to my webApplication I get the following exception:

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [Encoding]: Could
>   not find required filter class -
>   my.packagename.filter.EncodingFilter.class

In the console I get:

> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E:
>   [Servlet Error]-[action]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.packagename.filter.EncodingFilter

In my web.xml I have the following configuration:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Encoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.packagename.filter.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

I verified that this class exists in my project (projectName\src\my\packagename\filter\EncodingFilter.java) and that it implements the Filter interface.

What could be wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you check your `war` archive, is the class deployed with the rest of the app?

Comment: Yes, I found the filter in: \WEB-INF\classes\my\packagename\filter\